# PHP CMS Wonderings

Tags: php, html, content-management-system

I just want anyone to correct me if I'm wrong. Can I create a CMS by making a file where you log in as an admin and then you can write an article and send it to a database table. In another file display all articles from the table with `ORDER BY id`. To delete you simply make a delete script. Do I have to use any other languages like xml or something? Thanks!

**The question:** Can I make a simple cms by just using PHP and HTML?

Comment: Your question is unclear. It depends on what you really want to do as to whether you would need XML, for a simple CMS with basic [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,\_read,\_update\_and\_delete) you probably don't need anything other than PHP, HTML, a database and _maybe_ a little JavaScript.

Comment: I mean like in a blog website where the only thing displayed is text. Thank you and sorry for unclear question.

Comment: Answer to your question: yes, you can.

It really isn't possible to give any other answer to a question like this.

Comment: Every programmer writes his own CMS at some point. But be aware that it's only an exercise, don't try to sell it :)

Let's close this ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need other languages.

PHP and MySQL should be sufficient.

Well, the way the articles are displayed depends of HTML, CSS or JS codes you use.

Comment: Okay, thank you for clearing my mind.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking exactly. But you could easily write something like that in just PHP and HTML, and use a database to store the information.